# change ls color on OpenWrt

Tags: ls, colors, busybox, openwrt

I am not able to change the color of dir entries for `ls` command (dark blu is a very annoying color to read) on my OpenWrt device.
I've added the line

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;37:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

at the end of `/etc/profile` file, since OpenWrt hasn't any `bashrc` file, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Judging by source code, there probably no support for setting _colors_ by environment variable. It only exists to toggle color output on/off. But I can be wrong, just quick look at source where getenv() is called.

Comment: Also please note that OpenWrt uses busybox as every other embedded Linux distro, so certain features present on desktop systems usually unavailable in embedded environments.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on a Synology NAS where directories were printed like this on my terminal:

[image]

I resorted to replacing the colors using sed. I added this to my `.bashrc`:

```
function _ls() {
  out="$(/bin/ls --color=always "$@" | sed "s/\x1B\[34;42m/\x1B\[30;42m/g")"
  echo "$out"
}
alias ls=_ls
```

To actually make the output colored, I found it necessary to store the replaced output in a variable and echoing it as well as defining an alias (instead of naming the function `ls` itself).

Now the output looks like this:

[image]

Different wrapping, but slightly more readable.